# Planner Web Part only showing up for me. Gives error message for other users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, microsoft-planner

I have worked with SharePoint a good bit and have not had this problem yet. The planner web part (which is an awesome tool imo) will only show up for me when I create it. I am the "owner" of the site and the others needing to access are mostly on "contribute" some "read." Has anyone run into this problem? I have looked through many Microsoft support pages and have not found an answer. If you need more information let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use SharePoint Online and add the Planner web part in a modern page.

Whether the plans you add are public or private? If they’re private, whether the users are assigned to these plans? If not, assign the permission to the plans and check again.

Besides, what’s the error message you can view in the page? Please provide more info with us.

Comment: The error message says "Hmm, The Plan Your Looking for isn't here. The Plan has either been deleted or the link isn't correct" - When I go to site contents the planner web part is not there, so I am not sure where to do the permissions for this.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it was a very simple thing I was missing. Those you want to view a planner must be added in as members of the site before they can view it. I have been creating custom groups for certain departments to limit their access and not adding all in to member group. Quick fix that took a lot of trial and error.